# Error al realizar un método POST en un formulario con Spring

Tags: java, html, spring, http, thymeleaf

estoy intentando acceder a la ruta /new-user del Controlador POST pero me esta dando un error sobre que GET no es soportado.
No lo entiendo porque tengo declarada anotación de Spring @PostMapping y en el HTML tengo puesto como method=POST. Si alguien me pudiera echar una mano, para poder visualizar el horario o que me diera mas información de porque es el error. Gracias!

**registration.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User registration</title>
</head>

<body>

<form th:action="@{/new-user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

    <label>Usuario</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{username}">

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{password}">

    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{email}">

    <button type="submit">Registrar</button>

</form>

<p><strong th:text="${reponse}"></strong></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**UserController**

```
package com.example.myshop.contoller;

import com.example.myshop.domain.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        User user = User.builder().build();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "/users/registration";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/new-user")
    public String newUser(@ModelAttribute User user,
                          Model model) {

        System.out.println("Inserto al usuario por BBDD" + user.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("reponse", "Usuario registrado");
        return "/users/registration";
    }
}
```

**Error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que el  problema que tienes es por con la configuración de las vistas en tu aplicación.  estás devolviendo una cadena de "/users/registration" en ambos métodos del controlador. pero creo que es  probable que tu configuración de vistas esté buscando una ubicación diferente para las vistas, tienes que detallar mas de tu pregunta mi bro

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice que estás tratando de hacer un GET de una dirección no definida. Por lo que veo en tu código esto sucede en el método newUser, en la última línea. Prueba haciendo un redirect a registration (o tal vez a otra página) de esta forma:

```
return "redirect:/registration"
```